# .netTiers vs SubSonic

Tags: subsonic, .nettiers

I had some time this afternoon to run a head to head comparison between netTiers and SubSonic.

I used code generated using SubStage (part of the SubSonic 2.1 release) and I used RepositoryRecord as my base class.

I ran the same test against the same database using code generated by .netTiers 2.2

The test was a derivative of the one that Rob Conery used in his post:

http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/subsonic-scaling/

When i say derivative, I mean I just wrote 100,000 records into the database.

I repeated each test on the same PC three times.

I found that .netTiers accomplished the task in 90 seconds.

Subsonic completed it in 104 seconds.

There was no more than a one second deviation from these averages.

Comment: Create a blog and blog about it ;) SO is about questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a question? :)

As long as you steer cleer of the "deep" methods, and use judicial use of custom stored procs, I've always found netTiers performance to be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a question either, but if your intention was to find some big performance discrepancy among these 2 products, it seems that there's not much. So I would choose whatever offers me the best features for the task at hand.

Comment: You're right, it's not a question, more an observation. My motivation in posting the results was to provide information. I have no axe to grind with either solution